# storing the result of grep in a separate file

Tags: unix

I am searching something logs at the following directory

```
$ cd opt/app/abc/logs
```

Now the logs folder contains many different logs like

```
abc.log
def.log
wer.log
```

Now I need to search something in logs that I am doing n the following way as I wanted to know the names of the files first in which that entry is , Let say I am searching string 456

```
$bash
$  cd opt/app/abc/logs
$ grep -l 456 *
```

now I also want that it should store all the records of string 456 in a separate text file at the same location so that after that I can open that file to see the results sum up of string 456. How to achieve this?

Comment: Belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just output the command to a file:

```
grep -l 456 * > somefile.txt
```

You can do this for any command.

Comment: Thanks a lot , one more thing I want that when separate entries written in somefile.txt then it should also contain the name of the files from which those entries are extracted could you also please advise how to achieve that also

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
grep '456' * > outfile
```